# What does it mean when a js error points to a part of the viewstate?

Tags: .net, asp.net, ajax, debugging, asp.net-ajax

I am fairly inexperienced with asp.net ajax and am having a problem where a javascript error is thrown (object not found).

The debugger then stops and points to a substring of my viewstate it looks something like the following (not exactly this since my viewstate is huge) with the section between the ellipses highlighted:

```
<input type="hidden" name="__VIEWSTATE" id="__VIEWSTATE" 
       value="ObMUE...X78PmJHLJkWcHW4OXxH7/QxjqBI...m2" />
```

The callstack is equally unhelpful, reading

> JScript - form1 anonymous function

What does this mean and how do I go about debugging it?

**Edit:** As I have stated in some comments, Firebug is not an option.  The application is strictly IE only (we're trying to fix that but its a ways off) and doesn't work with any other browser.

Comment: what kind of ScriptResource.axd and WebResource.axd reference do you have?  I can't imaging the viewstate being involved in a JS error.

Comment: regular System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler.  Not even sure what WebResource.axd is, it is not referenced anywhere in my project as far as I know

Comment: Which debugger are you using? Have you tried the script debugger in IE8?

Answer (score 1):

The line number that is reported in your error is likely misleading.  I would recommend stepping through the javascript with a debugger.  I usually do this with IE and Visual Studio or the microsoft script debugger (check out [this link](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx) for directions).  There's also a good debugger in Firefox called [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/).

Or, if you're using Visual Studio 2008 you can just put a breakpoint on a javascript line and hit F5.

EDIT:  Whoops, I didn't realize you're already using a debugger.  Is your page emitting javascript via ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock, etc?  What about included files, are you using any js frameworks where the error might be coming from?

Comment: I know about Firebug, but firefox is not an option

Comment: Well if you've got VS2008 just put a breakpoint on a javascript statement and hit play.  If not check out http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2004/10/26/247912.aspx for instructions on javascript debugging in IE.

Comment: I know about script debugging (otherwise it wouldn't break into the debugger) but like I said, my callstack has exactly one entry and it is "anonymous function".  Any way I can look at what exactly that is?

Answer (score 0):

Debugging by browser error messages, especially IE, is notoriously difficult. Even simple error conditions, like an invalid reference, lead to extremely cryptic messages.

I would recommend a good Javascript debugger, such as FireBug. It makes finding and fixing javascript problems much, much easier.

Comment: Not an option.  Application is IE only.  Its actually a baked into the goddamn code that the browser must be IE.